# Angular upgrade is throwing an error when opening in storybook

Tags: javascript, angular, sass, storybook

I am trying to upgrade angular from `14 -> 15`, and when I do so I get the following error in my storybook:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')

Which then points to this block in the webpack build:

```js
function extractCommentsWithHash(input) {
    // Error references this line:
    return input.match(_commentWithHashRe) || [];
}

// Called from here:
    shimCssText(cssText, selector, hostSelector = '') {
        const commentsWithHash = extractCommentsWithHash(cssText);
        //....
    }
```

A few lines above that are these lines, so I believe the issue is in my angular install, in that I might be missing a package, or a configuration setting.

```js
// The deep combinator is deprecated in the CSS spec
// Support for `>>>`, `deep`, `::ng-deep` is then also deprecated and will be removed in the future.
// see https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/17677
```

In attempt to fix the issue, I added this to my `.storybook/main.js` for my custom webpack:

```
module.exports = {
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/i,
      use: ['sass-loader'],
    });
    return config;
  }
}
```

Here are some dependencies that I believe are relevant.

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10.4.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "sass": "^1.66.1",
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": ">=15.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": ">=15.2.9",
    "@angular/cli": ">=15.2.9",
    "@angular/common": ">=15.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": ">=15.2.9",
    "@angular/core": ">=15.2.9",
    "@angular/flex-layout": ">=15.0.0-beta.40",
    "@angular/forms": ">=15.2.9",
    "@angular/material": ">=15.2.9",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": ">=15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": ">=15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": ">=15.2.9",
    "@angular/router": ">=15.2.9",
    "rxjs": "^7.4.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  }
}
```